# How do I search my browser history in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: history, microsoft-edge

That's it. "How do I search my browser history in Microsoft Edge?"

I have searched Microsoft support and community pages but I still don't know.

Comment: I wonder if somewhat "standard" Ctrl+H and Ctrl+Alt+Del shortcuts do not work for Edge :)

Answer (score 9):

This is not a high speed answer, but was the only one available in 2017. The steps to search edge history are as follows:

1. Please follow the link to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/how-can-i-search-my-browsing-history-in-ms-edge/6ee108b7-d77f-4476-971e-a969231f0d3e , sign in with your MS id, and click the 'Me too' button under the question.
2. Open Windows 10 Feedback hub (press windows button; type feedback hub); and type "edge search history" into the search box. Click on the small word 'Upvote' on the first 5 or 10 issues you find which state the problem concisely and politely.
3. Wait about 3-36 months. You may find this step irritating.

You should then find that steps 4-5 work:

4. Browse to https://www.bing.com/search?q=ms+edge+new+features+search+history+-site%3Asuperuser.com
5. Follow the instructions in the first link.

You can get some relief during step 3. by:

1. Install FireFox
2. Open "Show All Bookmarks" -> Import and Backup -> Import Data from another Browser -> MS Edge

Comment: 12 months later. No dice. Also, step 4 sends me back to this page so I'm stuck in a loop.

Comment: :-(
I fixed the infinite recursion in the step 4 link though.

Comment: seriously this UPDATED super browser doesn't have a search for history, a stupid simple thing to program, and expects the user to browse through mountains of history to find what might be a single thing!!!!!!!   And it's now 2020 and I still don't find any search, did i miss and update?

Comment: it's a joke, I didn't want to install any additional browser not to pollute my machine with additional software, but come on... Even IE11 allowed you to search history

Comment: Well, 3-36 months turn out to be 5 years, but here it is at last: `Ctrl-H` now shows history

Answer (score 0):

If you open Explorer 11 at the same time as MS Edge is open, then you will find your browsing history and also the "Search" function that you used to see.

Answer (score -1):

Revisiting my question with an update. I have not found an answer and I guess it isn't possible.

However, you can **view your history** and **clear your browsing history**.
See [these Microsoft Support pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/10607/windows-10-view-delete-browser-history-microsoft-edge)

Quoting:
To view your browsing history, select **Hub > History**.

From that page you can:

1. Select **Clear all history**. Choose the types of data or files you want
   to remove from your PC
2. then select **Clear**.

Edited: As I thought I had an answer, but this doesn't really answer my original question.

Comment: This is a serious question.  Your original question asked how to search the history, this answer, explains how to clear it.  Are you saying you can search within Hub->History?

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood my original question today when I revisited it. It looks like I can display and clear my history but not search through it.

Comment: You should modify your answer so it answers your question.

Comment: If I had a useful answer, I would update it. The best I can say is that I have not found an answer - it is worth knowing this. I will remove distracting info in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Answer as of 2022:

1. Open Edge
2. Press `Ctrl-H`, or find 'History' under the 3-dots menu.
3. See the Search icon at the top of the now-open history panel

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1147146)

Comment: It answers the question *precisely*. This may be easier to understand if you realise that, now that the question can be answered (after 7 years), the question has become redundant.

Comment: "Wait for 2022." - What exactly does this mean? I am shocked at the incredibly low quality of this answer.  I am even familiar with feature that is coming to Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I take your point. “wait for 2022” presupposes that you came to this question between the years 2015 and 2021 which I accept not everyone has. I have edited the answer.

Comment: To be fair, this tells you how to OPEN history, and while the search field is there in the history panel, this question does NOT take that last step and explain that. It is a barely correct answer, but only for someone who is familiar with Edge is this an ACTUALLY correct answer. I recommend chilling a bit and using the EDIT button to add the few additional words needed to make this a much better answer than it is now.

Comment: Agreed, and done.

Comment: fwiw I think the real issue is that this was a serious and valid question in 2015 because the search history feature was impossible to find. Now that search history is implemented in Edge, the question itself can be retired. But SO doesn't yet have the notion of 'retire this question'

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll - This change to Edge hasn’t even happened yet, it’s going to be in a future build, and not currently in the stable build.